# Combining multiple rows in Python by the same value in Column A

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm looking to use Python to join multiple rows of data, from a CSV, into a single row. Each row has the same columns but with null values in different columns. Finally export it again into a CSV. Hopefully the examples below help clarify what I'm looking to accomplish.

Data Example:

```
Email                age    city             car
-----------------   -----   --------------   -----
JohnDoe@gmail.com    20     NULL             NULL
JohnDoe@gmail.com    NULL   San Francisco    NULL
JohnDoe@gmail.com    NULL   NULL             Mazda
henry@gmail.com      25     NULL             NULL
henry@gmail.com      NULL   Miami            NULL
henry@gmail.com      NULL   NULL             Honda
```

Expected result:

```
Email                age    city             car
-----------------   -----   --------------   -----
JohnDoe@gmail.com    20     San Francisco    Mazda
henry@gmail.com      25     Miami            Honda
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current output.

Comment: @AMC the issue is that, lets say for Person A, there are three events as such:

PERSON       ITEM
-------------       --------
A                    25
A                    Miami
A                    Honda

I managed to separate it each item into it's own column as in the data example in my question. Yet, I am still left with 3 rows for Person A but with each item placed in a different column. I want to place each Item into its respective column but all contained in a single row and print that into a new CSV file. Basically merge them into a single row instead of having 3 different rows

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], there may be a simpler way to resolve this by modifying the current program.

Answer (score 0):

If the NULL is NaN, then first sort values and drop NaN:

```
df['age'] = df['age'].sort_values().values
df['car'] = df['car'].sort_values().values
df['city'] = df['city'].sort_values().values
df = df.dropna()
print(df)
```

Comment: Why the `.values` ? Also, couldn't you call `.sort_values()` on the entire DataFrame?

Comment: I want to keep 'Email' untouched

Comment: Did you parse OP's data into an actual DF to test this? I can't be bothered to do it myself lol

Comment: @AMC i tested with a different df, i want to give you but alas i have closed the ipython shell

Answer (score 0):

data file tmp.csv:

```
Email,age,city,car
JohnDoe@gmail.com,20,,
JohnDoe@gmail.com,,San Francisco,
JohnDoe@gmail.com,,,Mazda
henry@gmail.com,25,,
henry@gmail.com,,Miami,
henry@gmail.com,,,Honda
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("tmp.csv", keep_default_na=False)
print(df)
Age = df[['Email', 'age']][df.age.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
City = df[['Email', 'city']][df['city'].astype(bool)]
Car = df[['Email', 'car']][df['car'].astype(bool)]

dfinal = Age.merge(City, on="Email", how = 'inner')
print(dfinal)
dfinal = dfinal.merge(Car, on="Email", how = 'inner')
print(dfinal)
```

Output:

```
               Email age           city    car
0  JohnDoe@gmail.com  20
1  JohnDoe@gmail.com      San Francisco
2  JohnDoe@gmail.com                     Mazda
3    henry@gmail.com  25
4    henry@gmail.com              Miami
5    henry@gmail.com                     Honda
               Email age           city
0  JohnDoe@gmail.com  20  San Francisco
1    henry@gmail.com  25          Miami
               Email age           city    car
0  JohnDoe@gmail.com  20  San Francisco  Mazda
1    henry@gmail.com  25          Miami  Honda
```